# Jenkinsfile pipeline syntax to insert list environment variable

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am having hard to trying to figure out how to add envVars to kubernet inside Jenkinsfile.

I am pretty sure the issue is in my syntax because I am getting following error

```
ava.lang.ClassCastException: class org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.
ContainerTemplate.setEnvVars() expects java.util.List<org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.model.TemplateEnvVar
> but received class java.lang.String
```

when I have it coded this way

```
stage("build") {
                agent {
                    kubernetes {
                        label 'kubernetes'
                        containerTemplate {
                            name 'jnlp'
                            image 'ubuntu:last'
                            ttyEnabled true
                            label 'label'
                            envVars '
                               envVar(key: "filePath", value: "/home/abcde/abc" )'
                        }  
                    }
                }
```

Can you guys please point me to right direction? How do I define list variable in Jenkinsfile?

**My Jenkinsfile setup**

```
pipeline {
agent any
parameters {
    string(name: 'Abc', defaultValue: 'origin', description: 'test project')
}
options {
    timestamps()
    timeout(60)
}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        parallel {
            stage("build") {
                agent {
                    kubernetes {
                        label 'kubernetes'
                        containerTemplate {
                            name 'jnlp'
                            image 'ubuntu:latest'
                            ttyEnabled true
                            label 'label'
                            envVars 'envVar(key: "filePath", value: "/home/abcde/abc" )'
                        }
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    container('jnlp') {
                        timeout(60) {
                            // build process
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
post {
    success {
        sh "success"
    }
    failure {
        sh "failed"
    }
    unstable {
        sh "unsable"
    }
  } 
}
```

With above code, I will get following error

```
ava.lang.ClassCastException: class org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.
ContainerTemplate.setEnvVars() expects java.util.List<org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.model.TemplateEnvVar
> but received class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i got this to work. Careful with Yaml syntax. Yaml doesn't like tabs

```
pipeline {
agent any
parameters {
    string(name: 'Abc', defaultValue: 'origin', description: 'The Gitlab project name')
}
options {
    timestamps()
    timeout(60)
}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        parallel {
            stage("build") {
                agent {
                     kubernetes {
                     label 'label'
                     defaultContainer 'jnlp'
                     yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    some-label: label
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jnlp
    image: ubuntu:latest
    tty: true
    env:
    -   name: 'filePATH'
        value: 'fileValue'
"""
                        }
                        steps {
                            container('jnlp') {
                                timeout(60) {
                                    // build process
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            success {
                sh "success"
            }
            failure {
                sh "failed"
            }
            unstable {
                sh "unsable"
            }
          } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at their example https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/f6cff5d7e9ce9da3279660159e0cb064efac534f/examples/selenium.groovy#L18

looks like in your case it should be

```
stage("build") {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            label 'kubernetes'
            containerTemplate {
                name: 'jnlp',
                image: 'ubuntu:last',
                ttyEnabled: true,
                label: 'kub_catkin_node',
                envVars: [
                    containerEnvVar(key: "filePath", value: "/home/abcde/abc" )
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the error message that I received  "rg.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 26: unexpected token: jnlp @ line 26, column 38.
                                   name:'jnlp'," . I had seen that example and was able to run successfully in Pipeline job. However, that syntax doesn't work if I placed inside Jenkinfile. That where I am having trouble with.

Comment: if it works as pipeline and doesn't work as as Jenkinsfile, sounds like you didn't copy the code properly

Comment: Hi Yuri, Sorry, I should have provided more information from the beginning. The reason above syntax won't work is because I am calling kubernet inside Pipeline {} instead of podTemplate{}. Please take a look at my original post. I added my Jenkinsfile setup. If I remove envVars line, i can run the job successfully. The issue is assigning value (list type) to envVars variable.

Comment: Hello Yuri, This wasn't supported in declarative pipeline. I followed this example: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/pull/306

Answer (score 0):

This is something supported from the UI and also from pipelines, but it might not be well supported in declarative pipelines.
One solution could be to use pipeline scripts. An other could be to check if its better supported in later version (if you are not already on the latest).

Comment: You were correct. This wasn't supported in declarative pipeline. I achieved using yaml. Here is where the issue was reported.https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47951. This is the example that I followed https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/pull/306